# Change Product Image on radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, magento

I want to change product image in my Magento Store on radio Button Click without using any extension.

I just want to change its color into Sepia and B/w  in to same image container on radio button click. 
(http://demo.lifestylewallart.com.au/)

As there will be number of images in my magento so code should be minimum.

I tried it using html and css on simple file.

Please have a look and let me know how we can use this in better way in magento store.

```css
 img {
     display: block;
     width: 50%;
 }
 .sepia {
     -webkit-filter: sepia(1);
     filter: sepia(1);
 }
 .gray {
     -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
     filter: grayscale(1);
 }
```

```html
<html>
    
    <body>Original : -
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png">
        <br>
        <div class="sepia">Sepia : -
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png">
        </div>
        <div class="gray">Gray :-
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png">
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Looking forward for quick support guys .. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code. It will help

```js
 $('input[name="color"]').on('change', function () {
  $('div.imageDiv')
        .removeClass('original sepia gray')
        .addClass($(this).val());
});
```

```css
     img {
     display: block;
     width: 50%;
 }
 .original { }
 .sepia {
     -webkit-filter: sepia(1);
     filter: sepia(1);
 }
 .gray {
     -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
     filter: grayscale(1);
 }
```

```html
<input type="radio" checked="checked" value="original" name="color" />Color<br /> <input type="radio" value="gray" name="color" />Gray<br /> <input type="radio" value="sepia" name="color" />Sepia</p>
<div class="imageDiv original">
<img id="photo" class="north" alt="" src="Tulips.jpg" /></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit 1**

`.removeClass('sepia gray')` used.

Added a new class `imageDiv` for div identification purpose.

```js
$('input[name="color"]').on('change', function () {
    $('div.imageDiv')
        .removeClass('sepia gray')
        .addClass($(this).val());
});
```

```css
 img {
     display: block;
     width: 50%;
 }
 .sepia {
     -webkit-filter: sepia(1);
     filter: sepia(1);
 }
 .gray {
     -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
     filter: grayscale(1);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="color" type="radio" value="gray" checked />Gray<br/>
<input name="color" type="radio" value="sepia"/>Sepia
<div class="imageDiv gray">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png" />
</div>
```

**Note** : In case you have a way for selecting the `div` uniquely, no need to add extra class and if there are a lot of possible different colors try using a switch case.

Comment: Can I implement this in Magneto Store. I am working on Neoshop Theme. I never done theme customization before. can you please tell me which file should be update with this code ..

Comment: If there are only two classes you can use `toogleClass()` also,

Comment: @RahulDambare I am sorry, I haven't worked on Magento before.

Comment: Hello Sir, How can we use for multiple classes ..?

Comment: @RahulDambare `.removeClass('sepia gray')` you can remove all color class first by separating them inside the `removeClass` with space like `removeClass('sepia gray black green etc')` and adding new one after by `addClass($(this).val())`.